# vma's in the kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory

I was reading up on virtual memory areas for linux processes [here](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-the-kernel-manages-your-memory/).

In the kernel vma linked list pointed to by the "mmap" field inside the memory descriptor(an instance of mm_struct).

I understand that there is a vma for each contiguous set of virtual addresses.

Are there vma's in that list corresponding to the kernel mapping?

Comment: All this vmas marked as user (appropriate flag is set in ptes), because they are belong to user space process, which owns this mm

Comment: what do you mean by kernel mapping? Memory mappings of the kernel address space?

Comment: @ChristopheAugier Yes, that is what I meant. Would there be a vma describing the pages present in the kernel, in the vma list of a process?

Comment: No, IIRC the mappings for the kernel are stored in a different list. Why are you asking (end-goal)?